# Can the number of Target features (y) exceed the number of Input features (X)?

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataset, dependent-variable, train-test-split

I am trying to perform a **train_test_split()** on a dataset. Before doing so and while I am assigning data to X and y variables, I realized I have **8 Input features a.k.a. Independent variables** and **45 Target features a.k.a. dependent variables**. Is it ok to have more Target features than the number of Input features before we split the data into train/test sets?

```
# split the data into train and test set

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = df[['StartDate', 'AvgTemp', 'DayOfWeek', 'HourNum', 'Precip.(inch)', 'Snow(inch)', 'TripDistance', 'TripDuration']]
y = df.drop(columns = ['StartDate', 'AvgTemp', 'DayOfWeek', 'HourNum', 'Precip.(inch)', 'Snow(inch)', 'TripDistance', 'TripDuration'])

# Split into test and training data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.17, random_state=42, shuffle=False)
```

The target features include the following

RidesPerDay - Total number of rides that took place in a day. 
Remaining 44 features include - Number of rides started/ended per day in each of the 22 different neighborhoods.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can! So long as the structure of the problem is clear and your input-output mapping makes sense, there's no reason you wouldn't have more output features than input features (for some problems, that can even be the norm rather than the exception). An algorithm might, for example, create an embedding from your inputs and then map from the embedding to many different features. Or it can combine your input features in various ways to create new output features. It could even take a single input and pass it through different transformations, eg imagine a toy machine that would take the surface of a cubic brick as input, and estimate its surface and edge length and even things like "how many cubic bricks of this surface would I need to build a typical suburban house" etc.